# Write lua_requiref in lua5.1

Tags: module, lua, load

I would like to use the function lua_requiref, but in lua5.1.
Is there a way to get the effect of

> lua_requiref

in lua 5.1?

Comment: You can find one implementation, which doesn't set a global var (which is the "modern" thing to do), [here](https://github.com/mooffie/mc/blob/ba2e8651a3a2d1a8f1f504e5aea8feacbc4c8ec9/lib/lua/capi.c#L700) (ignore "LUAMC_GUARD", "g_assert", and also pull in the implementation for "luaMC_getglobal2").

Comment: There's also [Compat-5.2](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.2) (and [Compat-5.3](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3)) which provide implementations of most of the newer Lua C APIs for Lua 5.1. Both of those have an implementation of `luaL_requiref`, the behavior is slightly different depending on the Lua version -- see the manuals for [Lua 5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_requiref) and [5.3](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_requiref).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [compat-5.3](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3) to get many of the newer lua C API functions in lua 5.1 (and 5.2).

The particular function you're looking for (`luaL_requiref`) you can find [here](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3/blob/ba065189ae67822ac9c69cc6ba633e3e8e123ef6/c-api/compat-5.3.c#L548)